# callback function when input character is not accepted by mask

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mask

I am using [jquery mask plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) and looking to callback functions when input is not valid.

When user enters an invalid character the character is removed by the mask automatically, how ever I want to display some hint to user, like "You have entered '1' which is not correct character, please enter a to z"

I asked it at https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/issues/180 and it is not supported yet. I wonder if anyone has same issue and have found any workaround (or any guide which part of the plugin should be changed)

Answer (score 0):

It has been fixed in version v1.9.0. Check it!